# Grails authorization on JS level

Tags: javascript, grails, spring-security

In my Grails app, some part of the GUI are generated automatically using JS (e.g. table rows). Now, I want to show/hide some of these GUI elements depending on the role of the user, e.g. ROLE_ADMIN may see the "delete" button, ROLE_USER may not.

My approach (I am using the Spring Sec Plugin):

```
_myview.gps HTML-part:
    <g:set var="isAdmin" value="${sec.ifAllGranted(roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN', "true")}" />

_myview.gps JS-part:
    if( '${isAdmin}' == "true" ){ ... }
```

This works, but I am not sure if this is save/clean/... and I'm a little afraid that it could be hacked easily.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delegate the check to Javascript if you are generating the Javascript in GSP anyway. Instead of `if( '${isAdmin}' == "true" ){ ...JS CODE... }` just write `<sec:ifAllGranted(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")>...JS CODE...</sec:ifAllGranted>`.

As for security, you will never be truly safe unless you check the user's roles on the controller/service level (so at the location your Javascript will call).

Comment: That will not work since I have about 500 lines of JS code and one single statement that is nested inside different loops and if blocks needs to know if the user "isAdmin"

Comment: Then I would say your original approach is just fine as long as any security sensitive code your admin-only JS may call also checks for ROLE_ADMIN.